# How to make react bootstrap tooltip to fit into container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am making a simple react app for which I am using react-bootstrap. Here I am trying to display a very very simple tooltip using `OverlayTrigger` like,

```
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement="bottom"
      overlay={
        <Tooltip id="tooltip" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner
        </Tooltip>
      }
    >
      <span>Hover over this text</span>
    </OverlayTrigger>
```

Displaying tooltip works fine but the alignment is not proper.

You can see that I have given continuous string inside tooltip (in my real app the string is dynamic and it is a token there and will be even longer than I have given above so I can't change this continuous string).

The problem is only a few parts of the string is visible while hovering, and rest of the string is out of the container.

**Working sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-tooltip-button-modal-wjybr

Tried giving `style={{ width: "100%" }}` to the tooltip but no luck.. It still doesn't fit into tooltip container..

I am in the need to make it fit into the container. So kindly help me to fit the entire string into the tooltip container.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @wentjun, Just hover over the span element with text ```Hover over this text``` and you will find the tooltip text showing only in partial and not the whole string is displayed.. Expected behaviour is whole string needs to be displayed inside the tooltip container.. Now it is not the entire string is displayed inside the black background tooltip container.. Eg: My string to display is ```thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner``` but it display only upto ```thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotf```..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `word-break` css property, and supply it with the 'break-all' value, such that it will be broken into different lines if the text is too long.

```
<Tooltip id="tooltip" style={{ width: "100%", wordBreak:'break-all' }}>
  thisisalongstringthanusualhencenotfilledincontiner
</Tooltip>
```

I have reproduced a working demo over [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-tooltip-button-modal-0e7ir).

Comment: Is it possible to make the container width horizontaly long?? Now we are using word break but if I want to show horizonatlly then how can i make the width of the tooltip container long?

Comment: @TestUser Hmm.. strange. For some reason, I can't change the width too